# Why does django-rest-framework authenticate() signature differ from django authenticate() signature

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm implementing a normal session authentication for my REST api with DRF and can't get it working, because DRF auth backends have `authenticate()` method with a different signature than normal Django's.

Here are my `AuthView` and `LoginSerializer`, they are mostly copied from DRF's authtoken package:

`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.http import Http404

from rest_framework import viewsets, views
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework import response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import authentication

from serializers import *
from models import *

class AuthView(views.APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication, )
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.validated_data['user']
            response_data = UserSerializer(user).data
            return response.Response(response_data)

        return response.Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`serializers.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import relations

from models import *

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(label=_("Username"))
    password = serializers.CharField(label=_("Password"), style={'input_type': 'password'})

    def validate(self, attrs):
        username = attrs.get('username')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        if username and password:
            import pdb
            pdb.set_trace()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user:
                if not user.is_active:
                    msg = _('User account is disabled.')
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
            else:
                msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "username" and "password".')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

So, `LoginSerializer` calls `authenticate(username=username, password=password)` as a normal django authenticate function.

It works with normal django `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`, but with DRF's `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` it fails due to incompatible signatures.

All the DRF's authentication backends expect `authenticate()` function to have signature `authenticate(self, request)`, which doesn't make much sense to me, as request doesn't contain user information yet.

What do I do?

Comment: Can you post your imports. You should be importing django's authenticate function

Comment: @KevanS. Yes, I do. Copied it verbatim from authtoken. Should I look for some special function in DRF instead? Django's `authenticate` is looping over all the backends, finds `SessionAuthentication` and attempts to apply its `authenticate()`, but fails due to incompatible signatures.

Comment: Authentication backends may accept any set of keyword arguments, but... DRF's `*Authentication` classes are not authentication backends as used by Django. They have no place in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, but should be used directly by your DRF views/viewsets, or configured in `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`.

Comment: @knbk Ah, you're right - my bad. Thank you. Should I delete this quesiton or will you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @knbk Hm, after I fixed this, session id won't be stored in a cookie, although POST returns Status 200.